# Trying to use multi threading to request data using an api call and store the data in a database

Tags: python, multithreading

I am requesting data using an API call and then store the data returned into a SQL Server. I am not sure how to share the data returned from the API call with function to write data to the SQL Server

```
def req_Data(row,q): 
    """ 
    function to request data from the API
    """

    for record in ds.request_realtime():
        if record.RP_ENTITY_ID in RIC.keys():
            row = [record.data['TIMESTAMP_TZ'],record.RP_STORY_ID,record.RP_ENTITY_ID,record.entity_name,RIC[record.RP_ENTITY_ID], round(record.event_sentiment_score,2),(record.relevance/100)]
        q.put(row)
def write_data(q): 
      row1 = q.get()
      cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO DB()
                       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',row1)
      cnxn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    row = []
    q = queue.Queue
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=req_Data, name = 'Thread1', args=(row,q)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=write_data,name = 'Thread2', args=(q)) 

    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 

    t2.start() 

    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
    t1.join() 
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
    t2.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I will do my best to solve it (seeing as I cannot test it myself). Things to note:

1. you need `q = Queue()` with parenthesis to create a queue object.
2. `row = []` isn't necessary, you can use a local `row` variable as shown
3. Items are removed from a `Queue()` with `q.task_done()` You can additionally use `q.join()` to proceed when no more items are in the queue (instead of joining your threads, but you can do that too if you want)

With these considerations it would look something more like:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time


def req_Data(q):
    """ function to request data from the API """
    for record in ds.request_realtime():
        if record.RP_ENTITY_ID in RIC.keys():
            row = [record.data['TIMESTAMP_TZ'], record.RP_STORY_ID, record.RP_ENTITY_ID, record.entity_name, RIC[record.RP_ENTITY_ID], round(record.event_sentiment_score, 2), (record.relevance/100)]
            q.put(row)


def write_data(q):
    while True:
        row = q.get()
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO DB()
                       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', row)
        cnxn.commit()
        q.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating thread
    q = Queue() # you were missing the ()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=req_Data, name='Thread1', args=[q])
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=write_data, name='Thread2', args=[q])

    t1.start()
    time.sleep(10)  # give our queue some time to fill
    t2.start()

    q.join()
```

However, if I were to use multithreading I would likely want several threads to load/unload my data. Since it would take more intimate knowledge of your script to do this for loading the data, I'll just show an example of unloading the data. It could look something like:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue


def req_Data(q):
    """ function to request data from the API """
    for record in ds.request_realtime():
        if record.RP_ENTITY_ID in RIC.keys():
            row = [record.data['TIMESTAMP_TZ'], record.RP_STORY_ID, record.RP_ENTITY_ID, record.entity_name, RIC[record.RP_ENTITY_ID], round(record.event_sentiment_score, 2), (record.relevance/100)]
            q.put(row)


def write_data(q):
    while True:
        row = q.get()
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO DB()
                       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', row)
        cnxn.commit()
        q.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating thread
    q = Queue() # you were missing the ()
    req_Data(q)
    # q is now full
    workers = 10
    thread_list = []
    for i in range(workers):
        t = threading.Thread(target=write_data, args=[q])
        t.start()
        thread_list.append(t)

    q.join()

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
```

Which is ideal, because now to scale the # of worker threads takes nothing more than adjusting the line `workers = 10` line. You could potentially run 10,000 threads with this script (probably shouldn't though! You'd still be making threads after the computation is done and it would be a waste of CPU time and slow your program down)

Hope this helps!